# Scala IDE Template Editor Broke

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-ide

I just downloaded the scala ide 4.0 release candidate 1 on my windows machine. I setup a basic play scala project and tried opening the the index.scala.html file with the New Play Editor and the file doesn't open.it looks like this: [image]

So then I tried opening the file in the regular play editor and when i type, the characters are typed in reverse:

[image]

Anybody know how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Is it just representation or the actual result is reversed as well? Maybe as a workaround you can type in reverse ;) What if you paste from clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a problem with your installation, if you are on Windows and you installed it under `Program Files`. Try moving it somewhere else (preferably without spaces in the path, though this is a permission issue). See this [long thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-ide-dev) on the Scala IDE mailing list.